# Download a file without SD card on android 2.3.4

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, unbricking, downloading

So I just booted up my old Xperia Neo and found myself to be unable to do almost anything.
I actually just wanted to download an app from the Playstore and test it.
But when I open the Playstore, I get `Error while retrieving information from server [RH-01]`. Googleing how to fix that I found a post where someone mentioned that you need to install "gapps". 
So I downloaded that using my PC.

But I cannot connect the internal phone storage to my computer, only the empty SD-card slot. No matter if I'm in MTP or MSC mode. 
So I fired up the browser on my phone and tried to download the files directly. But now my browser says "An SD card is required to download gapps[...].zip". I do have enough storage left on my phone.

So basically the phone is bricked.

Android version:  2.3.4
ROM: Xperia Slim v2.20
Root: yes
Browser: default
File explorer: none

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a long method. But it works.

Step one: download Aptoide [here](http://m.aptoide.com)

Step two: Install it. Obligatory warnings will pop up, just tick the Box "unknown sources" in settings > security.

Step three: Search for ES file explorer, and install that too.

Step four: Find your GApps link, and copy it

Step five: add that link as a bookmark in ES file explorer

Step Six: open link, and download GApps using ES file explorer.

- If This throws up the need for an SD card, use the settings in ES file explorer to fine tune it to internal storage.

Step Seven- Flash your GApps package (you have root, so I assume you know how that works.)

Step Eight: Profit! Oh and clear your cache and Davlik, and reboot.

Comment: How would I do step one? As I said, the problem is that I can't download anything.

Comment: @Forivin download it **through your mobile browser not the PC**

Comment: But that is exactly what doesn't work. As I said in the original question my browser says "An SD card is required to download ....". So I cannot download anything on my Android phone.

Comment: @Forivin is this a hint on the site itself, or as a pop-up/toast notification/normal notification? Can you provide the link?

Comment: This is a system notification and it appears no matter what I try to download. (The gapps file was about 5mb btw and I have 177mb of free internal storage.)

Comment: @Forivin Can you provide a link?

Comment: Sure. That's the gapps.zip that I tried to download: http://d-h.st/RzL

Comment: @Forivin ok. Try resetting app preferences (in the apps manager in the settings menu) and try again.

Comment: Okay. I left that phone at home, though. So that'll have to wait around 6 hours...

Comment: @Forivin Ok. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message. ... I hear it is possible to copy data over to the phone via ADB, but it's not straight forward because of the default read-only permissions on the internal storage...

Comment: @Forivin If the internal storage is read-only, you are, well, screwed. No amount of trickery will fix that (easily)

Comment: Well, you have to set access permissions for each folder from what I understood. That can be accomplished via ADB, too. But looking up all the commands and what exactly I need to do would be too time consuming. I mean this shit already cost me multiple hours. It's depressing...

Comment: Oh and I should clarify, the internal storage is not read-only in general. It's merely the default setting when accessing it via ADB.

Comment: @Forivin you could try adb push. 
Command:
adb push <Location of gapps on pc> <location of downloads folder on phone> (Without the arrows, of course) if you need to remount folders as read-write, remount /data. It should do it all at once.